Don't know how to put a ref val in DxSimpleItem
I try to make a small admin pannel form managing my project.
I made a file uploader for form in datagrid. Now after I upload an image with success I want to put the image [name.type] in a dxTextBox with the help of ref, but because the item is DxSimpleItem (not DxTextBox which have the :vlaue prop) I can't change the value. When I try with template, on save it just does not update data because it can't see any modification. Please help me, is my 2 day trying to figure it out. This is a DataGrid that has an DxForm in the DxEdit
enter image description here
<template>

  <div class="dx-viewport">
    <DxDataGrid
      class="h-data-grid-height"
      id="portofolioProjectsDataGridId"
      ref="dataGridRef"
      :data-source="dataSource"
      :show-row-lines="true"
      :show-column-lines="true"
      :show-borders="true"
    >

    <DxStateStoring
      :enabled="false"
    />

    <DxSearchPanel
      :visible="true"
      placeholder="Search..."
    />

    <DxColumnChooser
      :enabled="true"
      height="460"
      mode="select"
    />

    <DxPaging :page-size="25"/>

    <DxPager
      :allowed-page-sizes="pageSizes"
      :show-page-size-selector="true"
    />

    <DxEditing 
      :allow-updating="true"
      :allow-deleting="true"
      :allow-adding="true"
      :popup="popupOptions"
      mode="popup"
    >
      <DxForm :colCount="1">
        <DxTabbedItem>

          <DxTabPanelOptions
          :defer-rendering="false"
          />

          <DxTab
            title="General Data"
            :colCount="2"
          >
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="mobileImage"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="desktopImage"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="whiteTitle"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="yellowTitle"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="description"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
            data-field="showMoreLink"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="orderBy"
            />

            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="isShowMore"
            />
            
            <DxSimpleItem 
              data-field="isShown"
            />

          </DxTab>

          <DxTab
            title="Image"
            :colCount="1"
          >

            <DxSimpleItem>
              <template #default>
                <DxFileUploader
                  name="portfolioProject_image"
                  select-button-text="Select photo"
                  label-text="Select Mobile Photo"
                  accept="image/*"
                  upload-mode="instantly"
                  :upload-url="`${baseUrl}/portfolioprojects/projectsimages`"
                  :on-uploaded="onUploaded"
                  :upload-headers="headers"
                />
              </template>
            </DxSimpleItem>

            <DxSimpleItem 
              dataField="imageFileName"
              editor-type="dxTextBox"
              :editor-options="{ value: imageFileNameRef}"
            />
            
          </DxTab>

        </DxTabbedItem>
        
      </DxForm>
    </DxEditing>

    <DxColumn
      data-field="id"
      caption="ID"
      :visible="false"
      :show-in-column-chooser="true"
      :allow-editing="false"
    ></DxColumn>      

    <DxColumn
      data-field="orderBy"
      caption="Order By"
      :visible="true"
    ></DxColumn>

    <DxColumn
      data-field="mobileImage"
      caption="Mobile Image"
      :visible="false"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="desktopImage"
      caption="Desktop Image"
    ></DxColumn>
    
    <DxColumn
      data-field="whiteTitle"
      caption="White Title"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="yellowTitle"
      caption="Yellow Title"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="description"
      caption="Description"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="showMoreLink"
      caption="Show More Link"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="isShowMore"
      caption="Is Show More"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="isShown"
      caption="isShown"
    ></DxColumn>
      
    <DxColumn
      data-field="imageFileName"
      caption="imageFileName"
      :show-in-column-chooser="true"
      :visible="false"
    ></DxColumn>

    <DxToolbar>

      <DxItem 
        name="addRowButton"
      />

      <DxItem 
        name="columnChooserButton"
      />

      <DxItem 
        name="searchPanel"
      />

      <DxItem 
        location="after"
        template="refreshTemplate"
      />

    </DxToolbar>
    
    <template #refreshTemplate>
      <DxButton
        icon="refresh"
        @click="refreshDataGrid"
      />
    </template>

    </DxDataGrid>
  </div>

</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import { 
  DxDataGrid,
  DxColumn,
  DxColumnChooser, 
  DxEditing,
  DxForm,
  DxStateStoring,
  DxPaging,
  DxPager,
  DxToolbar,
  DxItem,
  DxSearchPanel
} from 'devextreme-vue/data-grid';
import {
  DxSimpleItem,
  DxTabbedItem,
  DxTabPanelOptions,
  DxTab,
} from 'devextreme-vue/form';
import { DxFileUploader } from 'devextreme-vue/file-uploader';
import { DxButton } from 'devextreme-vue/button';
import { createStore } from 'devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery';

const dataGridRef = ref(null);
const imageFileNameRef = ref(null);

const pageSizes = [10, 25, 50, 100]
const popupOptions = {
  title: 'Work & Experience',
  showTitle: true,
  width: 920,
  height: 550,
  hideOnOutsideClick: true,
  dragEnabled: false,
  showCloseButton: true
};
const baseUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api`;
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
const headers = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
};

const dataSource = createStore({
  key: 'id',
  loadUrl: `${baseUrl}/PortfolioProjects`,
  insertUrl: `${baseUrl}/PortfolioProjects`,
  updateUrl: `${baseUrl}/PortfolioProjects`,
  deleteUrl: `${baseUrl}/PortfolioProjects`,
  onBeforeSend(query, request){
    request.headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    };
  }
});

const refreshDataGrid = () => {
  if(dataGridRef.value != null){
    dataGridRef.value.instance.refresh();
  }
};

function onUploaded(e){
  // console.log(`Uploaded Image, result: ${e.request.response.replaceAll('"', '')}`);

  const imageId = e.request.response.replaceAll('"','');

  toastr['success'](`Image Uploaded: ${imageId}`);
}


</script>

<style scoped>


</style>


We need more than just the HTML to help.  This is partly a problem that must be solved with script code.  These DxSimpleItems are part of a form, what does the form-data object look like?  What happens in onUploaded function?  I can see you're trying to add a value to a DxSimpleItem with dataField "imageFileName", so when you upload the file, have you not tried setting the name to the form-data's imageFileName property?

I uploaded the full code, is this enought?

code should be minimal.  too much can be as bad as not enough...  all I asked was to see the JS related to the image uploading.  Regardless, I do see now in your onUploaded that you're not making any attempt to use the returned filename.  That is your problem.  I will post an official answer

well I did not try the e.file.name. But now when I upload the image it goes in my DxTabbedItem on Tab 0. I tryed to restart my back and front and no changes

you added imageFileNameRef.value = e.file.name to your function and that was the result?  where does it go exactly in DxTabbedItem?  a different field?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Well it just goes from second DxTab to first DxTab.
From "Images" to "General Data" but it doesn't update any field, like it just a jump, like a reset

The popup is rerendered for some reason.  Answer has been edited with a new solution that shouldn't do that.

This worked for the showing the data in the dxTextBox, but I cant upload it to my dotnet PUT api, just does not send any data, like nothing is edited.

the value is tied to a ref, independent from the rest of the form/grid data.  I don't know how you send the data, but you'll need to add the ref value to the rest of your data before sending the request.

so there is no other way? Before I started to learn vue I used Razor with clean js and html and I would put the value in imageFileName by id of the dxTextBox, so I wanted here to do something like this with ref

I'm not familiar with razor (not really familiar with devextreme either tbh).  Do you not create the request yourself?  A ref is just a proxy object.  It won't automatically add itself to a API request, that really doesn't make sense to me.  It'd be standard javascript to take the ref value (or any value really), append it to the rest of your form data, and assign it to the body of an API request

in devextreme if you put the data in the dataField, the devextreme will take care of it, like is simple. Razor is just a small framework like VUE for front end based on dotnet. I used on average js jquery and html + css for my websites.

onUploaded function receives as a parameter an event that includes the uploaded file information.  Bind the filename value to a DxTextBox component placed within the DxSimpleItem component
const imageFileNameRef = ref()

function onUploaded(e){
  imageFileNameRef.value = e.file.name

  const imageId = e.request.response.replaceAll('"','');

  toastr['success'](`Image Uploaded: ${imageId}`);
}

<DxSimpleItem dataField="imageFileName">
  <DxTextBox
    :value="imageFileName"
    @input="(e) => (imageFileName = e.event.target.value)"
  />
</DxSimpleItem>

You would think you should be able to use v-model on DxTextBox.  I found documentation that says you should be able to, yet it doesn't work. Maybe a bug or otherwise there's something I'm misunderstanding, but this worked for me.
